# Display an image for 1 sec on the view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, nstimer

What I want to realize is:

When I touch a button, the image display on the view for 1 sec, then the image disappear.

I know that a NSTimer will help, but i dont know how to write the right code...need your help, thanks.

```
- (IBAction)bodytouched:(id)sender {  
bodytouchedimage.hidden = NO;
    bodytouchedimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"beated.jpg"]];
    bodytouchedimage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(showPictures:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}


- (void)showPictures:(NSTimer *)timer {     
bodytouchedimage.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about that? It looks like it should work. Is it not for you?

Comment: Now, it works. I put a UIImageView on the view in the .xib file, make the connection, chose an image for it, and delete the code of line 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should to is call the `showPictures` function when you touch the button and then within the `showPictures` method you add a `NSTimer` that will call a hidePictures method 1 second later

```
- (void)showPictures 
{
    bodytouchedimage.hidden = NO;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(hidePictures) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)hidePictures
{
    bodytouchedimage.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using NSTimer, it would be easier to simply call your method to hide the image like this:

```
- (IBAction)bodytouched:(id)sender {  
bodytouchedimage.hidden = NO;
    bodytouchedimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"beated.jpg"]];
    bodytouchedimage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self performSelector:@selector(hidePicture) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}


- (void)hidePicture {     
bodytouchedimage.hidden = YES;
}
```

performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: is a method of the NSObject class.

Comment: It works！thank you！BTW you've missed a ":" after @selector(hidePicture:)